# Counting time in some ranges and start from half of hour in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have almost good code to count hours in some ranges of time but sometimes I have to start from for example 7:30 a.m and this is a trobule for me

I have a function that is able to count hours in time that I focus on it except days off when it comes to a Christmas etc.

Unfortunately I often have to count time from half of hours

```
Weekdays3 <- Vectorize(function(date1,date2){

dates <- seq(date1, date2, "mins")

dates <- dates[which(weekdays(dates) %in% c("monday",
                                              "tuesday",
                                              "wednesday",
                                              "thursday",
                                              "friday") & hour(dates) %in% c(8:15) & 
                         !(as.character(dates,format="%Y-%m-%d") %in% c("2018-01-01",
                                                                        "2018-01-06")))]

  length(dates)/60
})
```

I have to use this function to count hours from 7:30 a.m but now I am able to count only from 7 a.m or 8 a.m etc.

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do here. can you post an example of how you use this and what exactly the issue is? Even post the expected outcome to help us know what the problem is

Comment: I have to count hours for example from 7:30 a.m to 6 p.m only in business hours but my function is able to count only full hours for example from 7 a.m to 6  p.m